# sass mixin args don't get interpolated

Tags: sass

```
    $_1:rgb(25, 25, 27),
    $_2:rgb(252, 243, 243))
{
    --colors-1: $_1;
    --colors-2: $_2;
}
```

the code above when compiled to CSS gets interpreted as:

```css
/* ... */
--colors-1: $_1;
```

instead of:

```css
/* ... */
--colors-1: rgb(25, 25, 27);
```

Comment: a SASS variable cannot be assigned to a custom CSS property without string interpolation `#{ }`
[As described here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/css-vars). Because CSS custom properties allow any value to be assigned SASS cannot know if `$_1` needs to be replaced or if the value is literally `'$_1'`

Comment: wow, thx a lot I didn't know that was actually a thing!

Answer (score 0):

for some reason sass mixin args when used in `:root{}` they don't get interpolated

as a workaround for this I use `#{}` like so

```
--colors-1: #{$_1};
```